# Setting value of dropdown based on previously selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Currently, I have an API login page where the user can select a Location from a dropdown menu. After logging in, there is a landing page. The user then can go to a Test Client page, where they must authenticate again, with the same Location dropdown. Currently, I populate the ViewBag list of locations by setting it to

```
new SelectList(locations, "LocationID", "Name", model.LocationID)
```

Where locations is a list of my locations.
On the Test Client page, I populate my list from this previously built list stored in ViewBag.Locations. How can I carry over the user's selected value from this list on the original login page to the Test Client page? I'm having trouble with how to approach this.

I tried using

```
Request.Form["LocationID"]
```

but the POST request from the first form cannot be accessed from this first login page on the Test Client page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use Session State:

```
Session["LocationID"]=model.LocationID;
```

and then you can access from a different page. As stated in another answer, TempData does a similar thing but scoped differently. Finally, you can pass the value in the url.

Comment: I went with your solution after some discussion with coworkers. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can send it with the land page (for example in the URL), and then pass it to Test Client page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems weird that the user has to login twice with the same infos, but to answer you, you can use the `TempData` to pass data between controllers (assuming you're using a redirect).
TempData is available only for a user’s session, so it persists only till you read it and gets cleared at the end of an HTTP Request.
Example:

```
// In your login action, when it's done
TempData["Location"] = X;
return RedirectToAction(...);

// Then in your other action or it's view, just use
TempData["Location"] // and use it
```

If you're not using a redirect, then you'll probably want to store the value in, for example, the session or a database or something.

Answer (score 0):

A viewbag is used in scope of a **single** page generation. It does not retain data between different pages.

Which means that your question boils down to:

> How can retain data between different pages?

There are a few solutions here:

1. Use a **cookie**.

Cookies exists specifically so a user's browser retains information that can be retrieved by your webpage later on. This only works if both pages are in the same domain, as access to cookies is limited to the domain of the current page (e.g. a twitter cookie cannot access a facebook cookie).

2. Use **Session** data.

Session data exists specifically to have a temporary data store for a user. Consider session data as (sort of) a cookie on the web server, which only lasts for as long as a session (which is usually ended after 20 or so minutes of inactivity, or when the user closes their browser).

(TempData is similar to Session data)

3. Explicitly **pass the parameter** to the second page.

Instead of caching the value, simply make it a parameter of your second page's URL. For example: `http://www.example.com/SecondPage?selectedLocationId=123`.

Depending on how you're generating the page, either the web server or a script on the loaded web page can read the URL parameter and set the value of the dropdownlist accordingly.

---

There are more slutions available, but these are the standard solutions that don't require much extra work.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the above answers by jle and Haytam, you can use Session or TempData. I would not recommend URL query string parameters because you will have to take care to carry those parameters with every subsequent page visited before the user reaches TestClient Page.

However you also mentioned API login page. If you are using Web APIs then it will be difficult to access session level memory.

I would recommend a third approach i.e. creating a LastUsedLocationId field in IdentityUser model. In this way you can easily query the database for current user and fetch LastUsedLocationId and use it in your ViewBag like:

```
new SelectList(locations, "LocationID", "Name", user.LastUsedLocationId)
```

Where `user` is your database queried current user. Now you can keep your dropdown disabled as well on the TestClient Page with default location selected as the last used location.